# How to change the color of an svg element in Tailwind

Tags: reactjs, svg, tailwind-css

i am trying to change color svg element

```
  <svg
      xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
      className='fill-current h-28 align-middle m-2'
      width={size}
      height={size}
     >
      <circle
      r={radius}
      cx={halfsize}
      cy={halfsize}
      transform={transform}
      style={trackstyle}
      className='fill-current text-green-600'
    />
    <circle
      r={radius}
      cx={halfsize}
      cy={halfsize}
      transform={transform}
      style={indicatorstyle}
      className='opacity-75'
    />
  </svg>
```

but className='fill-current text-green-600'is not working

Comment: It works for me. See if `style={trackstyle}` does not conflict with the `className='fill-current text-green-600`

Comment: Thank you for your help but style={trackstyle} is not conflict from inspect mode  fill-current {
    fill: red;} working but when i try className='fill-current text-green-600' is not working